# Menu Popping up and down HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

[I can't use JQuery, if you wanted to know.]

I'm trying to make my Menu come up and down. (Duh) I don't know how else to explain it, I want so if you put your cursor near the top of the screen, the menu will slide down from the top, (like an animation), and it will go back up when you move your cursor away from the top of the screen.
Code:

```css
body {
 background-color: #eeeeee;
}
Rounded {
 padding: 17px 17px;
 padding-top: 50px;
    background: #dddddd;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
Header {
 font-style: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 3px;
 font-size-adjust: bottom;
 color: #ededed;
}
Black {
 color: 000000;
}

Backer {
 
}

Bod {
 padding 15px 15px;
 padding-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Games-rade</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css">
 <script src="Javascript/Java.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <center>
 <header>
 <rounded><Black>---------------------------------- </Black><a href="index.html">Main</a><text>        |        </text><a href="about.html">About</a><text>        |        </text><a href="buy.html">Buy</a> <Black>---------------------------------- </Black></rounded>
 </header>
 </center>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <Bod>
 <h3> Hello. </h3>
 </Bod>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: If you can use Jquery...where is your code for that? At the moment you're asking us to do it for you...and that's not what SO is for,

Comment: Also what are `<rounded><Black> etc`...they're not standard Html elements? Also `<center>` has been deprecated and in not used under HTML5

Comment: Pure css: http://jsfiddle.net/xanwx7d9/

Comment: I just wanted to know how....What's SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS transitions on block elements to move your header in and out of view.

Below is a rough example using most of your code.

As an aside, you should really avoid using non-standard html elements (such as `rounded`) while learning; instead, add classes to standard elements. One last note, from looking at some of your CSS rules, I would recommend looking into the difference between display types, specifically `block` and `inline`, and what styles you can apply to each.
A good intro can be found here: http://learnlayout.com/display.html

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

rounded {
 padding: 17px;
  background: #dddddd;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 17px;
}
header{
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #ededed;
  display:inline-block;
}

header rounded {
  display:block;
  transform:translateY(-100%);
  transition:transform .5s ease;
}

header:hover rounded {
  transform:none;
}

Black {
 color: #000000;
}

Bod {
  display:block;
 padding 15px 15px;
 padding-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
 <title>Games-rade</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css">
 <script src="Javascript/Java.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <center>
 <header>
 <rounded><Black>---------------------------------- </Black><a href="index.html">Main</a><text>        |        </text><a href="about.html">About</a><text>        |        </text><a href="buy.html">Buy</a> <Black>---------------------------------- </Black></rounded>
 </header>
 </center>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <Bod>
 <h3> Hello. </h3>
 </Bod>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/8s5fety8/) to you using jquery:

```
(function(){
    var top_menu = $(".animation");

    $(".menu").on("mouseenter", function(){
        top_menu.slideDown();
    });

    $(".menu").on("mouseleave", function(){
        top_menu.slideUp();
    });

})();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Uh...I can't use JQuery. (It's my fault, I accedently posted "can" instead of "can't")

Comment: @Mario1luigi9 If you can't use jQuery, please remove the jQuery tag from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *too* familiar with the language myself but Codecademy has a tutorial on making interactive webpages and I believe it covers just this. Plus, it's a good way to learn CSS/jQuery.

The course is at http://www.codecademy.com/en/skills/make-an-interactive-website/

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you want to get away from non-standard tags. I would also suggest using CSS transitions. Assuming that you want your menu to be accessible once you've scrolled down the page I've used a fixed position container. Hopefully the simplicity of the code will help you understand what is happening.

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <nav><a href="#">Item 1</a> | <a href="#">Item 2</a> | <a href="#">Item 3</a></nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed; /* Allows you to stick the container in place */
    top: 0; /* Stick it to the top of the page */
    left: 0; /* Make sure it's all the way to the left as well */
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    line-height: 30px; /* Easy way to vertically center single line text when you know the height of the container */
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; /* Allows you to adjust placement of element */
    top: -31px; /* Move up 30px from its normal position */
    transition: all 1s; /* */
}

.menu-container:hover nav {
    top: 0; /* When menu-container is hovered move nav to top 0 from -31px */
}

.content {
    margin-top: 35px; /* Using this so that your content doesn't start behind the menu */
}
```